# Issue with monkeypatching methods and references

Tags: python, monkeypatching

I was wondering if anyone could explain and offer a solution to this issue:

```
$ cat object-override-methods.py 
class A:
    def foo(self):
        return 1

class B:
    def foo(self):
        return 1

for klass in A, B:
    orig_foo = klass.foo
    def foo(self):
        return orig_foo(self) * 2
    klass.foo = foo

A().foo()
B().foo()
$ python object-override-methods.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object-override-methods.py", line 15, in <module>
    A().foo()
  File "object-override-methods.py", line 12, in foo
    return orig_foo(self) * 2
TypeError: unbound method foo() must be called with B instance as first argument (got A instance instead)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An explanation would help; just posting code with no context does not encourage people to help out.

Comment: my answer mostly looked like RichieHindle's so I didn't bother, but for what it's worth, monkey patching == bad

Comment: Ideally, an API will not define two identical methods in two different classes. Sometimes poor design necessitates more poor design :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`orig_foo` is a global variable which changes value with each pass through the loop. After the loop is done, `orig_foo` refers to `B.foo`.

The inner functions `foo` (one or each pass through the loop) both use the global value for `orig_foo` when they are called. So they both call `B.foo(self)`.

When calling an "unbound method" like `orig_foo`, Python2 checks that the first argument is an instance of the appropriate class. `A().foo()` does not pass this check. (Interestingly, this check was removed in Python3, so there would be no TypeError raised, and this bug may become harder to find.)

To fix this, you must bind the value of `orig_foo` to the appropriate `klass`.
You can do that by making `orig_foo` a local variable of `foo`. One way to do that is to make `orig_foo` an argument of `foo` with a default value. Python binds default values at the time a function is defined. So `orig_foo=orig_foo` binds the local variable `orig_foo` to the current value of the `klass.foo`:

```
for klass in A, B:
    orig_foo = klass.foo
    def foo(self, orig_foo=orig_foo):
        return orig_foo(self) * 2
    klass.foo = foo
```

Comment: Nice idea using a default argument. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because `orig_foo` is defined at global scope, you're trampling on its value each time round the loop.  That trampled value is then shared by each of your new `foo` methods.

A simple fix is to move the code into a function, like this:

```
def rebind_foo(klass):
    orig_foo = klass.foo
    def foo(self):
        return orig_foo(self) * 2
    klass.foo = foo

for klass in A, B:
   rebind_foo(klass)
```

That ensures that each new `foo` method gets its own value of `orig_foo`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now. orig_foo was being evaluated when the method was being called, not at the time the method was defined. Thanks a lot.